# 404 on 'j_spring_security_check'

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I think the best way to explain my problem is with a screenshot:

imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=16564

Basically I'm trying to follow this mkyong tutorial

(http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/)

for a school project. I get redirected to the login page, but when i try to login with any credentials, i get the action value printed on the url.

Could it be a encoding related problem? Any idea how to solve it?
Here's my controller, security.xml and web.xml.

Thanks!

spring-security.xml:

pastebin.com/MS7VYSfs

web.xml:

pastebin.com/EpGPc40Q

login.jsp:

pastebin.com/8Q4hxdVs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess you haven't imported the standard JSTL library in your login page, hence you get the literal `<c:url` embedded in the page. You should check what is actually rendered in your browser when it loads the page.

Either add

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

at the top of your login page, or try it with

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
```

Comment: You were right, it was the taglib missing. 
I knew it was something THAT stupid :D

Thank you so much :)